# GCP - gsutil export block at the last file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

when i use gsutil command to export my drive and shared drive, the download work perfectly fine until the last file. I come to 99% in 1 hour and the last file on the screenshot is processing since 3 hours.

I already try to do 1 folder by 1 folder but it's still the same.

Did you already encounter the problem ?

[Screenshot of the last file blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHQ7o.png)

Regards,

Comment: can you add what commands you're using in the question, also the size of files/folder

Comment: Sur @Prany, the command is : `gsutil -m cp -r \   "gs://takeout-export-c23a1768-3cf2-4c59-914b-cfd224165f2c/20210802T210130Z/" \   "gs://takeout-export-c23a1768-3cf2-4c59-914b-cfd224165f2c/Rapport\ sur\ l'état.html" \   ./`